# How to set socks5 proxy from command line in Linux when using Gnome?

Tags: linux, proxy, gnome, socks5

I can set socks5 proxy using Gnome Settings.  However, how can I set it using a shell script?  It turns out the setting just set a new environment variable called `ALL_PROXY`.  But it seems the variable is set at gnome session level, which will not work if I just add the environment variable in `.bashrc`.  How can I do that from command line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the help from [gnome forum](https://discourse.gnome.org/t/how-to-set-socks5-proxy-from-command-line/13068/2?u=ttc0419), I finally get it.  All the gnome settings can be modified using command `gsettings`.  The keys that controls the proxy settings are:

```shell
[user@archlinux tmp]$ gsettings list-recursively org.gnome.system.proxy
org.gnome.system.proxy autoconfig-url ''
org.gnome.system.proxy ignore-hosts ['localhost', '127.0.0.0/8', '::1']
org.gnome.system.proxy mode 'manual'
org.gnome.system.proxy use-same-proxy true
org.gnome.system.proxy.ftp host ''
org.gnome.system.proxy.ftp port 0
org.gnome.system.proxy.http authentication-password ''
org.gnome.system.proxy.http authentication-user ''
org.gnome.system.proxy.http enabled false
org.gnome.system.proxy.http host ''
org.gnome.system.proxy.http port 0
org.gnome.system.proxy.http use-authentication false
org.gnome.system.proxy.https host ''
org.gnome.system.proxy.https port 0
org.gnome.system.proxy.socks host '127.0.0.1'
org.gnome.system.proxy.socks port 1080
```

To set the SOCKS5 proxy, we can using the following commands:

```shell
gsettings set org.gnome.system.proxy.socks host example.com
gsettings set org.gnome.system.proxy.socks port 1234
gsettings set org.gnome.system.proxy mode 'manual'
```